# Unable to cast BsonArray to BsonInt32

Tags: c#, mongodb, c#-4.0, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

Below is the code, that fetches the bson element first and then its corresponding value, but even the bson value here is being returned as complete 'key: value' pair from the 2nd iteration onwards, it gives a casting error stating unable to cast bson array to bson int32.

I want to fetch only the values of every element and then sum up those values and display them in a new bson element, i am stuck because of the casting error. can someone help me out on this?

```
foreach (string nestedAmount in document.Names)
                {
                    BsonElement element = document.GetElement(nestedAmount);
                    BsonValue elementValue = element.Value;



                    //summation logic

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the solution on my own, below is the code that works correctly now

```
    double Total = 0;    

    foreach (BsonDocument nestedDocument in myDocument["doc"].AsBsonArray)
                        {
                            Total += Convert.ToDouble(nestedDocument["amt"]);
                        }
```